# How to make keyboard enter button say “Search” when any one type in browser other wise it used as Enter as usual?

Tags: java, android, android-softkeyboard

I am developing a custom keyboard.In this, I use an Enter button which works well as an enter key when I typed in a text or messaging But I want to use this button as a search key when any one type in a browser. In my keyboard, this works as newline instead of search.How can I handle this with the same button?

I am following this Link to make this Keyboard

https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/create-a-custom-keyboard-on-android--cms-22615

here is code

```
  if(primaryCode == Keyboard.KEYCODE_DONE ) {
        ic.sendKeyEvent(new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could use:

```
   if(primaryCode == Keyboard.KEYCODE_DONE ) {
         if(Patterns.WEB_URL.matcher(editText.getText().toString()).matches()){
             search();
         } else {
             ic.sendKeyEvent(new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN,KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER));  
         }
   }
```